# Google Place API, advanced place details: amenities, crowd, accessibility

Tags: google-places-api

I'm successfully using Google Places API to get details like name, address, phone, lat/lng, opening hours, etc. No problem with that.

However, the data I can't get a hold of is the deeper data.

For example, if you open up a McDonald's, and click on its short description, it will show things like Amenities, Crowd, Atmosphere, Accessibility.

Question is - is it possible to access this information via Places API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details). That information is not returned by the API.  You can link directly to that place on Google Maps to show your users that information though.

Remember that APIs like this usually don't return all of the information available to the native service so that the native service (in this case Google Places) retains a competitive advantage.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please check out this link to learn more about our community: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: Is Amenities details available now? If yes, how to get it?